Proof of existence of universal cover
I was reading through a proof that a path-connected, locally path-connected, and semi-locally simply connected space $X$ has a universal covering space $\tilde{X}$ that I found on the internet here: https://romanaranda123.files.wordpress.com/2018/07/a-note-on-covering-spaces.pdf
There's one particular detail of this proof that I haven't been able to understand, namely the proof that the lift of a path $\gamma$ in $X$ to the path $\tilde{\gamma}$ in $\tilde{X}$ is continuous. To be specific, in the paragraph (near the bottom of page 3) where he writes:

On the other hand, given $s\in\gamma^{-1}(U)$, since $\beta(1)$ is also in $U$ and $U$ is path connected, we can pick a path $\eta$ in $U$ connecting $\beta(1)$ and $\gamma(s)$. Then $[\gamma_s] = [\beta \cdot \eta]\in U_{[\beta]}$ and $\gamma^{-1}(U)\subset\tilde{\gamma}^{-1}(U_{[\beta]})$.

I don't understand from where the equality $[\gamma_s] = [\beta\cdot\eta]$ follows. It doesn't make sense to me that just because $\gamma_s$ and $\beta\cdot \eta$ have the same endpoints, that they should be path-homotopic to each other.
I believe all the relevant information here is: $\gamma$ and $\beta$ are paths that start at a fixed $x \in X$, and $\beta(1) \in U$. The definition of $\tilde{\gamma}$ is $$ \tilde{\gamma} : [0,1] \rightarrow \tilde{X}, \quad \tilde{\gamma}(s) = [\gamma_s]$$ where  $$ \gamma_s : [0,1] \rightarrow {X}, \quad \gamma_s(t) =\gamma(st) \quad \forall s\in [0,1]$$ and all equivalence classes $[\cdot]$ are path-homotopy classes, or homotopy classes rel $\{0,1\}$. $U\subset X$ is a path-connected set such that the homomorphism $\pi_1(U) \to \pi_1(X)$ induced by the inclusion $ U \hookrightarrow X $ is trivial.
So, to summarise my question, why should $\gamma_s(1) = \gamma(s)$ and the concatenation $\beta \cdot \eta$ be path-homotopic in $X$?
Thank you very much!

$\gamma_s(1)=\gamma(s\cdot1)=\gamma(s)$, with $t=1$. But I agree their proof is a bit suspect when it deals with the second inclusion. It is not given that the entirety of $\gamma_s$ has image contained in $U$ so semilocal simple connectivity need not apply to say $\gamma_s\simeq\beta\cdot\eta$ in their context. There's a simple fix though; the idea is just that if $\gamma_s$ is $\beta$ composed with a path in $U$ then nearby $s$ we can walk along $\gamma$ and remain entirely in $U$, showing $\gamma_t$ is also $\beta$ composed with another path for $t$ close to $s$.
Here's how I'd put it. If $\tilde{\gamma}^{-1}(U_{|\beta|})$ is empty, there is nothing to show. So suppose it's not and take $s$ within it. By definition, there exists $\eta_s$ a path contained in $U$ such that $\gamma_s\simeq\beta\cdot\eta_s$. Let us take an open interval $J$ about $s\in I$ such that $\gamma(J)\subseteq U$; possible by continuity. For any $t\in J$, we can say that $\gamma_t\simeq\gamma_s\cdot\delta_{s,t}$ where $\delta_{s,t}$ is the path $I\ni u\mapsto\gamma(s+u(t-s))$ and $\delta$ has image contained in $U$. So $\gamma_t\simeq\beta\cdot(\eta_s\cdot\delta_{s,t})$ where $\eta_s\cdot\delta_{s,t}$ is a path contained in $U$ and it follows $[\gamma_t]\in U_{|\beta|}$.
Therefore $s\in J\subseteq\tilde{\gamma}^{-1}(U_{|\beta|})$ and the right hand side must be open since $s$ was arbitrary.
Morally the homotopy $\gamma_t\simeq\gamma_s\cdot\delta_{s,t}$ is just a respeeding. Here's how you could explicitly do it: $$\Gamma(u,v):=\begin{cases}\gamma(2\alpha(v)\cdot u)&0\le u\le\frac{1}{2}\\\gamma(\alpha(v)+(2u-1)(t-\alpha(v))&\frac{1}{2}\le u\le1\end{cases}\\\alpha(v):=(1-v)s+\frac{vt}{2}:s\to\frac{t}{2}$$

@Confused It was not a typo. I want to show $J\subseteq\tilde{\gamma}^{-1}(U_{|\beta|})$ because that's exactly the kind of thing we have to do to show continuity. I've taken an arbitrary $s$ in the preimage and shown it has a neighbourhood $(J)$ which is still contained in the preimage. Showing $s\in\gamma^{-1}(U)$ is very easy and is not my concern here. Reminder: it is still important, very important, $\gamma(s)\in U$ so we can use continuity of $\gamma$ to find this interval $J$ with $\gamma(J)\subseteq U$.

@Confused And I recommend Hatcher's treatment of this material. It's pretty good.

Right! This does make sense, my bad. Thanks very much for your help!

@Confused You're welcome
